# Syntax error in JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, class, syntax, conditional-formatting

I'm playing with a little something and here's the code I have so far

```
class Person {
constructor(sex, name, age) {
    this.sex = sex || (
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            let sexes = ['f', 'm'],
                picker = Math.round(Math.random());
            picker === 1 ? this.sex = sexes[0] : this.sex = sexes[1];
        } );
    this.name = name || (
        let names = ["Jane Doe", "Jon Doe"];
        sex === 'f' ? this.name = names[0] : this.name = names[1]; );
    this.age = age || (
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 20 + 1) + 20);
        age = rand; ) ;
} }//end class
```

I'm getting this following error and I'm not sure what to do about it =\ :

```
/Users/Username/Desktop/code/file.js:23
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token for
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Comment: The error is there because the `||` operator expects a boolean expression to its right, but finds the `for` instead. So if you are trying to get a boolean out of that for loop, maybe replace it with a function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Nisarg Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5894241/nisarg-shah) mentioned in the comments, the code is expecting a value following the `||`, not a few lines of code to execute.

Instead you could put those lines of code into a function and call it in order to provide the default value when no value is provided.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(sex, name, age) {
    function getRandomSex() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        let sexes = ['f', 'm'],
          picker = Math.round(Math.random());
        return picker === 1 ? sexes[0] : sexes[1];
      }
    }

    function getName(sex) {
      let names = ["Jane Doe", "Jon Doe"];
      return sex === 'f' ? names[0] : names[1];
    }

    function getRandomAge() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 20 + 1) + 20);
    }
    this.sex = sex || getRandomSex();
    this.name = name || getName(this.sex);
    this.age = age || getRandomAge();
  }
} //end class

var me = new Person();
console.log(me);
```

Comment: also, thank you and @Nisarg Shah for the clarification on what the || operator's behavior.